# How to join Linq entity grouped results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, uwp

I have a list of 114 ISO Controls. Each control joins to a "Control to Documents mapping entity". I need help please to show the documents related to each control. I can achieve what I need with the code below but not at all good practice.

```
               var items = from d in AnnexAControls.GetAll() // there are 114 controls
                            join e in db.ControlToDocumentMaps on d?.ControlId equals docm.ControlId into grp // one control maps to multiple documents
                            select new
                            {
                                Control = d,
                                MappedDocuments = grp
                            };

                foreach (var item in items) // loops 114 controls
                {
                    var documents = from d in item.MappedDocuments
                                    join e in db.Documents on d.DocumentId equals e.DocumentID into doc
                                    select new { doc };

                    // Shows the documents related to each AnnexAControl
                    foreach (var document in documents) 
                    {
                        var documentTitle += $"{document.doc.First().DocumentTitle}{Environment.NewLine}";
                    }

                    //...
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here would be to utilize navigation properties between your controls and documents:

As a basic example:

```
public class Control
{
    [Key]
    public int ControlId { get; set; } 
    // ....
    public virtual ICollection<ControlDocument> Documents { get; set; } = new List<ControlDocument>();
}

public class ControlDocument
{
    [Key, Column(0)]
    public int ControlId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(1)]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ControlId")]
    public virtual Control Control { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DocumentId")]
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    [Key]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    // optionally can have a virtual ICollection<ControlDocument> Controls {...}
}
```

This will likely need additional configuration to map out the many-to-many relationship but should serve as a starting point to compare to your existing schema. If your entities have navigation properties for the DocumentControl available in the Control and/or Document entities already then you should be good to go. If not, I would highly recommend adding them as this represents a lot of the capability that EF can provide for building queries vs. treating EF & Linq like a substitute for SQL querying with manual joins etc.

To display documents per control if you wanted to project those into a :

```
var controlDocuments = db.Controls
    .Select(c => new 
    {
       c.ControlId,
       c.ControlName,
       Documents = c.Documents.Select(d => new 
       {
            d.Document.DocumentId,
            d.Document.DocumentTitle
       }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

This would return a structure of anonymous types containing a list of Controls /w Id and Name, and each control a list of applicable Documents with Id, and Title. From that you could consume the data and generate strings or whatever is needed, or for simple string building expressions these could be written into the `Select` expressions directly.

AFAIK EF Core still requires that the ControlDocument joining entity is declared and mapped in the relationships. With EF6, if the ControlDocument table merely contains the ControlId and DocumentId as a composite key then you can simplify the mapping so that Control contains an `ICollection<Document>` and EF can be configured to use a joining table without a matching entity.